# MFC C++ in a Modeless Dialog Show a Modal one

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog, modeless

I have a modeless dialog.  When I try and do a .DoModal() from there, it shows the dialog, but it still allows you to interact with the modeless dialog.

This is how I create modeless dialog:
    MyMainEditorWindow = new CMyMain(this);
    MyMainEditorWindow->Create(CMyMain::IDD,GetDesktopWindow());
    MyMainEditorWindow->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

To do a modal one, from that modeless window, I do

CMyDlg myDlg;
int dialogbox = myDlg.DoModal();

Is there any way to do what I want?  Where in modeless window, a dialog from it makes its window wait until it's decided.

Comment: The edit doesn't change the answer. The *modal* dialog needs to have the *modeless* dialog as it's parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the parent window in the modal dialog's constructor. Docs for CDialog constructor say that if you set it to `NULL`, it uses main application window as the parent, and the default if unspecified is `NULL`.

Comment: +1 I always try to set the parent (it's almost always `this`), rather than using the default NULL